# Using Trip Parser API with Gmail API

Tags: amadeus

I tried using the API, but it returns Error parsing. Even an example code in Amadeus for Developers collection for Postman returns ERROR when I run it.
Also I am using Gmail API and would like to know which part of the message should be passed to the Trip Parser API. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested and the Postman example seems to work. Please take a look at this blog article: https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/guide-to-the-trip-parser-api. If you still face any issue please contact us at developers@amadeus.com with your code sample

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did follow that article and got "in progress" status and then "error" soon after.  Would it help if I gave you a job id?

Comment: Yes please, send to developers@amadeus.com: the job id, the exact request you use and if possible when you tried so we can use the timestamp to find your request in the logs.

Comment: @AnthonyRoux I got a word from your support that there is indeed an issue with the test environment - https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/